# How to call a view of an entity on application-side

Tags: database, view, entity, domain-driven-design

Let's assume performance is key. For a specific use case only specific columns from entities (joined together) are needed. Because of performance only the needed data is loaded (not all columns from the entity). In the end it is only a view of the entities.  This results in multiple views of the same entity if different use cases are defined.

There are lots of ways to implement. But how would you call that? Views are usually on database-side, right?
Do you know some concepts for dealing with that problem?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a form of CQRS.  There's a write model (all the columns in this case) and arbitrarily many read models for which only a subset of the columns are meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is usually referred to as [Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS)](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

In that pattern there's separate read & write models (at the very least from the application's perspective).

When it comes to naming the actual "views" I don't think there's necessarily a high level of consistency. Some call them "read models", others call them "views" and they could possibly be seen as "projections" although those are generally associated with projecting a stream of events.

I think I'd call them "views" not to overload the "read model" terminology which also refers to the entire query model. Then again you might be concerned to distinguish "database views" from those so perhaps clarify with "application-level view" vs "database view" if there's confusion in a discussion?

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right. CQRS itself ist just that. Of course it can be combined with event sourcing but its not necessary.